# How to change background VBA Editor?

Tags: vba, ide, darkmode

I would like to have VBA in dark mode. I have followed all instruction I have found online, but I have this background left on my variables

Is anyone able to tell me how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: Did you change the colors for `Identifier Text` in the settings?

Comment: If you are curious: The color settings are stored in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VBA\7.1\Common`, look at `CodeBackColors` (and `CodeForeColors`). You should see a list of `0` for "normal" settings resp. `1` for your dark mode - except for the 4th and 5th value (Breakpoints and Execution Point).